# Extract text from within a cell and paste text in corresponding column using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that has data organized like so:

[image]

The user will insert multiple or as many text files as they want therefore each time the user imports a new text file the data gets placed beneath the previous import so the filepath, depth, A0, A180, etc are all present each time a text file is imported. 
I want to be able to get the corresponding date and time (2003-11-03 17-52-04) for each file under the column 'Reading Date'. However I'm not sure how to go about this.

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code to import the data:

```
Sub Import_Textfiles()
Dim fName As String, LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow))
        .Name = "2001-02-27 14-48-00"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(14, 14, 8, 16, 12, 14)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("W16").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0

    Dim strShortName As String
    Dim strInitialDir As String


    'Adding Updating Location to Excel Sheet:

    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 1   'column A has a value of 1
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    strShortName = fName

    'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol) = ("Updating Location: " & strShortName)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show your code so we can see what you have tried and help you from that point onwards?

Comment: Yes of course! This is my code to import the text file data into the sheet:

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this near the end of the `With` block:

```
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .ResultRange.Columns(.ResultRange.Columns.Count + 1) = Now
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Slai, but I do not want todays date within that column, I want the date that is within the file path.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to do what I need it to do with the following code:

Sub Import_Textfiles()
Dim fName As String, LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
    Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow))
    .Name = "2001-02-27 14-48-00"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(14, 14, 8, 16, 12, 14)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


End With
Range("W16").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0

Dim strShortName As String
Dim strInitialDir As String


'Adding Updating Location to Excel Sheet:

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String
Dim fileDate1 As String
Dim fileDate2 As String


sourceCol = 1   'column A has a value of 1
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

strShortName = fName
fileDate1 = Mid(fName, InStrRev(fName, "\") + 1)
fileDate2 = Left(fileDate1, 19)


'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol) = ("Updating Location: " & strShortName)
        Cells((currentRow + 1), (sourceCol + 7)).Select
        Cells((currentRow + 1), (sourceCol + 7)) = "Reading Date"
        Cells((currentRow + 1), (sourceCol + 7)).Select
        Cells((currentRow + 2), (sourceCol + 7)) = fileDate2

    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Thanks for the other suggestions!!